# Why progress bar updates with simple thread?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, progress-bar, ui-thread

Android documentation says "UI can't be updated by a non-UI thread", but In case of progress bar, no exception is thrown. My progress bar is being updated by a non ui (raw Thread). However, I get the exception in case of other widgets. I just want to clarify why this is happening (that should not happen)! here is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ProgressBar progressBar;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        progressBar=findViewById(R.id.progress_bar);

        MyThread thread=new MyThread();
        thread.start();
    }

    public class MyThread extends Thread{
        @Override
        public void run() {
            super.run();
            int i=0;
            while(i<=100){
                i++;
                progressBar.setProgress(i);
                try
                {

                    Thread.sleep(50);

                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: They specifically wrote `ProgressBar` to handle this scenario. See [`refreshProgress()` in the `ProgressBar` source code](https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/widget/ProgressBar.java#L1605-L1622), where they handle the case when you update the progress from a background thread.